# I am working on a Node application where I am reading huge amount of data per second and running out of heap memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, worker-pool

I am working on a Node application where I am reading huge amount of data per second and I am releasing the memory as soon as it is not used but after some time the application runs out of the heap memory. How can I overcome this issue?

I have tried to release the memory right after using it. here's the code. I am using WorkerPool and 8 threads.

```
export const writeSBSData = async (data, loginData) => {
    let { id: rowId, fromdate, todate, unit, nm } = data;

    let params = {
      "reportResourceId": 7320,
      "reportTemplateId": 0,
      "reportObjectId": unit,
      "reportObjectSecId": 0,
      "reportObjectIdList": [],
      "interval": {
        "from": fromdate,
        "to": todate,
        "flags": 117440512
      },
      reportTemplate: reportTemplateSBS,
      remoteExec: 0,
    };

    let vehicle_class = null;
    let unit_data = await getItem(-1, unit, loginData);

    if(unit_data.pflds){
      for (let key in unit_data.pflds) {
        if (unit_data.pflds[key].n === 'vehicle_class') {
          vehicle_class = unit_data.pflds[key].v ? unit_data.pflds[key].v : null;
        }
      }
    }
  
    let report = await executeReport(params, loginData);
  
    let headerIndexMap = {};
    report.reportResult.tables[0].header.forEach((header, index) => {
      headerIndexMap[header] = index; 
    });
      
    if (report.reportResult.tables?.length > 0) {
      let tableData = await getTableData(0, loginData);
      let tableData2 = await getTableData(1, loginData);
      let tripDriverCode = tableData[0].c[16] ? getValue(tableData[0].c[16]) : 0;
      let delta_speed = 0;
      let insertValues = [];
      let seat_belt_violations = [];
      let harsh_break_violations = [];
      let harsh_acceleration_violations = [];
      let panic_violations = [];
      let night_trip_violations = [];
      let ip_box_violations = [];
      let external_power_loss_violations = [];
      let driving_distance_violations = [];
      let rest_violations = [];
      let harsh_cornering_violations = [];
  
      for (let i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        let d = tableData[i];
        if (tripDriverCode == 0) {
          tripDriverCode = d.c[16] ? getValue(d.c[16]) : 0;
        }
        if (i == 0){
          delta_speed = 0;
        } else {
          delta_speed =  getValue(d.c[headerIndexMap["SPEED*"]], 'FLOAT') - getValue(tableData[i-1].c[headerIndexMap["SPEED*"]], 'FLOAT')
        }
      
        insertValues.push(createInsertValue(unit, d, nm, delta_speed, vehicle_class, headerIndexMap));

        let sbsData = transformSbsData(unit, d, nm, delta_speed, vehicle_class, headerIndexMap);

       
        if(sbsData.panic != 0){
          console.log(sbsData.panic);
          console.log(sbsData.time_epoch);
        }

        if(sbsData.panic == 1){
          panic_violations.push(sbsData);
        }

        if(sbsData.night_trip == 1){
          night_trip_violations.push(sbsData);

        }

        if(sbsData.ip_box == 1){
          ip_box_violations.push(sbsData);
        }

        if(sbsData.driving_distance_violation == 1){
          driving_distance_violations.push(sbsData);
        }

        if(sbsData.main_power_event == 1){
          external_power_loss_violations.push(sbsData);
        }

        if(sbsData.speed > 5 && sbsData.rest_violation == 1){
          rest_violations.push(sbsData);
        }
      }

      tableData = null; 
  
      await Promise.all(tableData2.map(async d => {
        await insertTrips(d, tripDriverCode);
      }));

      tableData2 = null; 

      if(panic_violations.length > 0){
        let violations = await extractViolations(panic_violations, 'panic', 4);
        
        if(violations.length > 0){
          let sql = generateSql(violations);
          console.log(sql)
          await queryDb(sql);
        }
      }

      if(night_trip_violations.length > 0){
        let violations = await extractViolations(night_trip_violations, 'Night Driving Violation', 0);
        
        if(violations.length > 0){
          let sql = generateSql(violations);
          await queryDb(sql);
        }
      }

      if(ip_box_violations.length > 0){
        let violations = await extractViolations(ip_box_violations, 'IP Box Tempering Violation', 0);
        
        if(violations.length > 0){
          let sql = generateSql(violations);
          await queryDb(sql);
        }
      }

      if(driving_distance_violations.length > 0){
        let violations = await extractViolations(driving_distance_violations, 'Driving Distance Violation', 0);
        
        if(violations.length > 0){
          let sql = generateSql(violations);
          await queryDb(sql);
        }
      }

      if(external_power_loss_violations.length > 0){
        let violations = await extractViolations(external_power_loss_violations, 'External Power loss Violation', 0);
        
        if(violations.length > 0){
          let sql = generateSql(violations);
          await queryDb(sql);
        }
      }

      if(rest_violations.length > 0){
        let violations = await extractViolations(rest_violations, 'Rest Violation', 60);
        
        if(violations.length > 0){
          let sql = generateSql(violations);
          await queryDb(sql);
        }
      }
  
     let sql3 = `select count(*) as count from new_opal_unit_events where unit=${unit} and eventStartTime >='${fromdate}'  and eventEndTime <='${todate}' `;
      let events = await queryDb(sql3);
        
      if (events[0].count > 0) {
        logger.log(`${events[0].count} events are written for unit ${unit}`);
      }

      tripDriverCode = null;
      delta_speed = null;
      insertValues = null;
      seat_belt_violations = null;
      harsh_break_violations = null;
      harsh_acceleration_violations = null;
      panic_violations = null;
      night_trip_violations = null;
      ip_box_violations = null;
      external_power_loss_violations = null;
      driving_distance_violations = null;
      rest_violations = null;
      harsh_cornering_violations = null;
    }
  
    let sql = `UPDATE recache_querybatcher SET success = 1 WHERE id = ${rowId}`;
    await queryDb(sql);
  };
```

Comment: This is really not readable, i will advise you:

1. Before diving into working with databases or frameworks, kindly get started with the programming language itself. Clearly, I can see you haven't studied enough or at all about JavaScript, because:

   i.  How can a function be this long \n

   ii. What is it with the let and null everywhere\n

   iii. In JavaScript, the community has moved towards camelCasing \n

   iv. Also, you will hardly find a project using a raw query, because it can quickly get overwhelmed, just in a few cases where an extension needs to be written.

Comment: 1: I understand that the function should be refactored which I am going to do eventually.
2: [let](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/var-vs-let-const-easiest-explanation-ever-asit-rohan-dass/) is limited to the scope of the function and I am assigning null to the variable so that memory is no longer referenced after use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.